# why does Statement.executeQuery gets stucked in java

Tags: java

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM mydatabase.Adminitrators";
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs =  st.executeQuery(query);
```

the program gets stucked at the last statement:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: how big Administrators table is?

Comment: Are you able to execute the same query from any sql client and get the result?

Comment: ... and how long has it been "stuck" for?

Comment: Stuck means what ? Does it show any error stack trace ? Did you try that query through the command line of the database server ? If you find any error stack trace post it along with the question. This will help.

Comment: Didn't you forget an 's' in `mydatabase.Adminitrators` ?

Comment: What happens when you execute above query using a MySQL client? How many seconds it takes to complete? According to the given name "Administrators", I don't think this table has so many rows though.

Comment: Nope it doesn't throw any exception and it doesnt either move to next step. It doesnt do anything at all.

Comment: @Nishant it only contains one record

Comment: @ManishSharma yes sql client returns result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my stupid mistake. (Spelling Mistake)
Thanks @Ben van Gompel for mentioning it.